# Importing historical notes into Chatter Feed

Tags: api, chatter

I want to import freeform notes from another system into Salesforce.

I'll like to import this data into the Chatter feed using the API (we'll write a custom importer).  But I need to set the created date so the chatter posts are marked as occurring at the right time.

I know Salesforce will enable a setting to allow you to set the created date when creating records for this kind of historical concept, what I don't know is if this feature is available with the chatter feed.

1. Are there issues with doing this?
2. Can I set the 'created date' on the chatter feed if Salesforce support enables this feature for the org.

Comment: As far as I know they can open up these audit fields to allow you to set the created date for any object.  I can't say that I have ever tried it with chatter feeds, but its my recollection that SF support told me it was available for all standard fields, I could be wrong, but thats what I remember from the last time I had them open one of the fields for me.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce Support can enable the audit fields in any object for certain period.

I think you can use dataloader to import feed items.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have done this before using SOAP API, and i believe REST API can as well.
You can both set CreatedById, CreatedByDate to chatter feed item, comment, like, content(chatter file).
And you don't need contact salesforce support when using API.